# The exception of CSMA/CD in 802.3

Tags: ethernet

It is stated that CSMA/CD is *generally* used in 802.3. I understand that there is an exceptional case that does not fit into the generalization.

I searched about it but I couldn't find that case. Is there such a case? What would that case be? I suppose it is about the length of the data or the distance between the stations but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Collision detection is *rarely* used, because most network connections are full duplex.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your connection from Switch to host is full duplex you can switch CSMA/CD off as it is no longer required